# Should I wait until my direct manager is back from vacation to share recommended changes?

Tags: professionalism

I've written a document outlining pitfalls I've identified in our development process and policies, and my recommended solutions, that I intend to share with management (not entirely unsolicited). This document is highly relevant to my direct manager (the Senior Developer) and to the CEO and a couple other departments.

As I write this, the document is finished and ready to be shared, and it is early morning on a Friday. However, the Senior Developer is on vacation for two weeks as of Monday.

Should I send this document to the Senior Developer and CEO now, or wait until the Senior Developer returns from vacation?

Comment: I would avoid doing the manager's job while he's gone. It might burn bridges between you and your manager. Managers help spread information and decide on courses of action. So doing things while he's away could be seen as doing things behind his back. Some could appreciate doing some work for him, but I wouldn't risk it.

Comment: If your direct manager asked for it, wait. Is the CEO aware of what you are doing? If not wait.

Comment: The fact that you're asking whether or not you should wait indicates that this email can in fact wait.  If it was super urgent and couldn't wait, then there's no need for the question at all...

Comment: Could you clarify your own role?  If your direct manager is a Senior Dev, does that make you a Junior Dev?

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings except that this bypasses the direct manager of the OP - he would probably like to review or even amend before it goes up the chain.

Comment: @HorusKol - But this seems very important to the OP.  Why should he wait?  If the Senior had any valuable input, I would think the Document the OP created would not have been needed in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's pros and cons to either choice:

**Send it now**

Pro:

- Shows that you completed the work in a timely manner
- Means you won't forget to send it later

Con:

- Your manager is possibly going to come back to a mountainous inbox of unread mail and it might get lost in the "noise"
- He might read his mail and glance at it when his off but it probably won't get his full attention (because he is on holiday) which might lessen it's impact

**Send it when the come back**

Pro:

- It will arrive when he is around to pay attention to it and it will be fresh in both your minds
- You aren't contributing to his inbox avalanche
- If you are sending it to more than just your direct manager it makes more sense to involve everyone at the same time - otherwise the conversation would get fragmented

Con:

- It may appear that you have taken blinking ages to send it.

It's the last "pro" I listed for the "send it later" option that clinches it for 
me. As HLGEM points out in his comment:

> I would never send something like this to the CEO without having sent a draft to the manager first. you always give your immediate boss a chance to see something that could cause him problems once the CEO gets involved. If the doc is drafted now, I would see if my boss wanted to see it today before he goes on vacation, so he can have a chance to think about it before you pass it up the line.

Cutting your direct manager out of the loop on something like this (unless you have been explicitly requested to do so by someone senior to them) or even giving the impression that is what you are doing is generally a **really** bad idea. If I've interpreted this wrong and your direct manager is the only recipient at this stage, in which case it's not really a big deal either way.

Comment: I would never send something like this to the CEO without having sent a draft to the manager first. you always give your immediate boss a chance to see something that could cause him problems once the CEO gets involved. If the doc is drafted now, I would see if my boss wanted to see it today before he goes on vacation, so he can have a chance to think about it before you pass it up the line.

Comment: @HLGEM agreed... if this is to be sent to both the CEO and his manager then waiting is by far the most sensible option

Answer (score 7):

Wait.

Since nothing can happen until he's back, then wait until he's back before you send it.  You'll then have a chance to talk things over.

If he has access to email while he's on vacation, he'll only think that you're trying to stab him in the back while he's away by cutting him out of the loop and going above his head.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to wait for 2 weeks? Send it now and get it over with. Whether to read the document before or after the vacation is their decision, not yours. In any case, their vacation has nothing to do with you.

Edit: I interpreted the Monday in your question to mean the *next* Monday. If they are already on vacation, then do [as Snark Shark says](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/100262/3192).